# How make Ember back to precious page's old vertical position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a long list of items in first page. I click one item to go to the item detail page(route). Then if I go back, by clicking either back button in the browser or JavaScript history back function, I end up at the beginning of the list. This is not what I want. How can I go back to where I was?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the addon [memory-scroll](https://github.com/ef4/memory-scroll)

Comment: It works. Be nicer if it works with infinity add on too. Thanks!